# There is a javascript delay when hovering over images

Tags: javascript

I have four images on a page and when I hover over the image, I want a horizontal div to move up on the bar, and when the mouse pointer moves off of the image, I want it to slide back down. Now when I do this is works fine, however there seems to be a delay. Also, if I move back and forth repeatedly, the delay is more and the slider ends up going up and down on its own for a few seconds. Here is the code, please help!

```
$('.indexgall').on('mouseenter',function()
{
    $(this).addClass('hoverimg');

    $(this).children().animate(
    {
        top: 150
    }, 600, function()
    {

    });
});

$('li').on('mouseleave',function()
{
    $(this).removeClass('hoverimg');

    $(this).children().animate(
    {
        top:250,
    }, 600, function()
    {

    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a transition CSS property on the element? Or, transition-delay?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it doesn't look there should be a delay. Can you post a JSFiddle to show this problem in action?

To address the latter concern, you want to be using the JQuery `stop()` method to stop the animation by cleaning the animation queue.

This can be done, like so:

```
$(this).stop().animate({
    width: 240
}, 500);
```

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngxvk7v6/).